# Create and Write data to Bigquery partitioned table from spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Can we create a partition table(with integer type) in Bigquery on the fly and load data to it from spark

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create [integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions) programmatically with [BigQuery client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition) in your Spark job, and then write data to it through the [Spark BigQuery Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#writing-data-to-bigquery).

Comment: Thanks for your response, will try it out